# Get data using json api wordpress

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rss, android-volley

I think using JSON Parse more functional better than RSS Reader if you wanna create native mobile android application. Installing Wordpress and Plugin JSON API in backend then using Asynctask vs Volley Library to frontend Android. Show data to ListView - OnItemClickListener to get Item more details. but unfortunately JSON File have something different in Content Array because content including img class.

```
"content":"<p><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-7\" src=\"http:\/\/localhost\/novemberproject\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/1522040_20130503100310-300x233.jpg\" alt=\"1522040_20130503100310\" width=\"300\" height=\"233\" \/><\/p>\n<p>A sports car (sportscar) is a small, usually two seater, two door automobile designed for spirited performance and nimble handling.<\/p>\n"
```

If result put to TextView, will get an error :

```
" Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) ".
```

Anyone have time to explain, how to implementation on this case study? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your data to empty array. And convert to json, this array. So, you do not have write JSON yourself. *with: `json_encode`

Comment: convert to json I'm using plugin JSON API in wordpress. The problem is that the image inside the content, Whether I must to create a custom php file?